# ORA-00934: group function is not allowed here. Issues with WHERE SUM(x) = (SELECT MIN(SUM(x)))

Tags: sql, oracle10g, aggregate-functions

Need to get the last_name and first_name of the client with the smallest payment. Payment has different invoice payments divided by method of payment, so I need to SUM the payments with the same invoice number before I decide which is the smallest payment. Payment and Client are different entities/tables linked by a third one, Invoice. The relationship is one to many between the entities goes like this:

```
Client -----<= Invoice ------<= Payment. 

SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name FROM client c, invoice i
wHERE i.id_client_fk1 = c.id_pk
AND i.num_pk = (SELECT num_invoice_fk1 
                FROM payment 
                WHERE SUM(amount_after_tax) = (SELECT MIN(SUM(amount_after_tax)) 
                                               FROM payment 
                                               GROUP BY num_pk));
```

Client has `PK` used in Invoice as `FK`, and Invoice has `PK` used in Payment as `FK`.

I want to use exact same logic I put in the code but obviously it has to work. Need to compare `WHERE SUM(amount_after_tax) = SELECT MIN(SUM(amount_after_tax))`.

I get that this doesn't in `SQL` (hence the title of my question), but that's the logic I could come up with to explain it.

```
 SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name FROM client c, invoice i
 WHERE i.id_client_fk1 = c.id_pk
 AND i.num_pk = (SELECT num_invoice_fk1 FROM payment
                 WHERE amount_after_tax = (SELECT MIN(SUM(amount_after_tax)) 
                 FROM payment
                 GROUP BY num_pk));
```

This code runs in `SQL` but it doesn't do what I want because is compares only individual payments to the `MIN(SUM(amount_after_tax))`. Let's say I have 3 payments for one invoice. I need to sum them to be able to compare them, with `MIN(SUM(amount_after_tax))`. Also tried using HAVING and it doesn't work. Maybe I'm to inexperience. Please help

[image: Payment Table]

[image: Entity Relationship Diagram]

Comment: MIN(SUM()) is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use having for filter aggregated  result   (not where)

```
SELECT c.first_name, c.last_name 
FROM client c, invoice i
WHERE i.id_client_fk1 = c.id_pk
AND i.num_pk = (SELECT
     num_invoice_fk1 
    FROM payment HAVING SUM(amount_after_tax) = 
      (SELECT MIN(amount_after_tax) 
       FROM payment 
       GROUP BY num_pk)
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Window functions come to mind:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name
from client c join
     (select i.id_client_fk1, i.num_pk, sum(p.amount_after_tax) as total_amount,
             row_number() over (order by sum(p.amount_after_tax) asc) as seqnum
      from invoice i join
           payment p
           on p.num_invoice_fk1 = i.num_pk
      group by i.id_client_fk1, i.num_pk
    ) ip
    on i.id_client_fk1 = c.id_pk
where seqnum = 1;
```

The subquery aggregates the data and uses `row_number()` to enumerate the results.  The outer query then brings in the names and chooses the first row.

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- The logic here is simple.  Just aggregate to calculate the total and pull out the first row.

EDIT:

Because you want only one row, you can also use `rownum`:

Window functions come to mind:

```
select c.first_name, c.last_name
from (select c.first_name, c.last_name,
             i.id_client_fk1, i.num_pk, 
             sum(p.amount_after_tax) as total_amount,
      from invoice i join
           payment p
           on p.num_invoice_fk1 = i.num_pk
           client c join
           on i.id_client_fk1 = c.id_pk
      group by i.id_client_fk1, i.num_pk
      order by total_amount asc
    ) ip
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but could you explain to me this code. I basically don't understand the middle portion. Or, is there's some reading material that I can do about that? What's the name of it?